# Is there a way to compile all JSP files in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea

Is there a way to enable compilation/verification of all the JSP files in a project? I am doing a big refactoring and want to make sure I don't break any of the JSP files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's possible in IntelliJ IDEA:

[image: validate]

Comment: As of version 14, no validators are listed...anybody have any clue how to get this now?

Comment: Is there a way to set the Jasper compiler version? I'm using Java 8, but the JSP validation isn't.